# DynamoDB: ValidationException: The provided key element does not match the schema

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-dynamodb, aws-sdk-js, aws-sdk-nodejs

I'm getting the error `ValidationException: The provided key element does not match the schema` trying to find the field `username` in my database, when querying the `id` manually I get a response but with the `username` I get the error.

```js
const readKey = async (table, queryData, column) => {
  const params = {
    TableName: table,
    Key: {},
  }

  // { TableName: 'users', Key: { username: 'Maarten' } }
  params.Key[column] = queryData

  return await new Promise((res, rej) => {
    dynamodb.get(params, (err, data) => {
      if (err) {
        rej(err)
        console.log(err)
      }
      console.log(data)
      res(data)
    })
  })
}
```

The response:

```sh
  message: 'The provided key element does not match the schema',
  code: 'ValidationException',
  time: 2019-11-24T23:50:37.472Z,
  requestId: 'RHQF02LFVE7V3NNSGDBF8JR97RVV4KQNSO5AEMVJF66Q9ASUAAJG',
  statusCode: 400,
  retryable: false,
  retryDelay: 14.742327788838905
```

when I change the params to this:

```
const params = {
  TableName: table,
  Key: {
    id: '22601770-37ea-47ce-9814-bd979ca4c841',
  },
}
```

I get the response:

```js
{
  Item: {
    id: '22601770-37ea-47ce-9814-bd979ca4c841',
    password: '$2b$10$f/gXRrSCCALPRedCIxOwVuhzi2EX07DeEDVF4h10UuUN.DgYY2Hnq',
    username: 'Maarten'
  }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You can not query on a non hashkey field, in this case maybe only `id` is a hashkey, `username` does not. If not as I said, provide the way you create the table.

Comment: @hoangdv So what's the best way to tackle this problem? How do you check users against the database?

Comment: You can create a GSI (Global secondary index) and set `username` as a hashkey.

Comment: If you want to search by a value that is not your partition, you could add a sort key to your table on a value like `username` and do a `query()` operation for your sort key. Query is less intense than scan, but note that get operations will require both partition and sort key

Comment: I made `username` my primary key yet still I'm receiving the error. Could you provide an example of an implementation?